# amazon-dynamodb-dax support for AWS SDK for JavaScript v3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dax, aws-sdk

We have recently upgraded services to use **AWS SDK for JavaScript v3**.

We have one issue, that we cannot upgrade services that are working with DynamoDB DAX.
In AWS SDK v2, we used **amazon-dax-client** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-dax-client).But with v3, seems that amazon-dax-client client library, does not work.

Does anyone have example of how to use **DAX** with **AWS SDK for JavaScript v3**

Comment: It doesn't work yet. See here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/232